# java invalid IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't know why but once in a while when I start my program I get the error message below. Most of the time it runs fine, but every once in a while when I start it I get this error. It doesn't make any sense because as you can see it's trying to reference `index 1 of a size 3 array`, which should not be a problem. The array is an `ArrayList` and I'm using a nested for loop, not a for each but the normal `for(int i =0; i < size; i++)` style, in both t inner and outer loop. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm running into some kind of bug. I'll post the section of code reporting the error below.

This particular instance happened here:

```
int x = fontArray.get(i).getPaintLetters().get(i2)[0]*Animator.pixMulti;
```

But I've seen this happen in the other array calls in that section as well. It only happens once the first time it's called. It runs in a loop and never happens again for that instance of the program. Thank in advance.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 3
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
        at Engine.Board.paintFont(Board.java:461)
        at Engine.Board.paintComponent(Board.java:332)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5223)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1572)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1495)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1265)
        at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5171)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4982)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:824)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:807)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:807)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:782)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:731)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(RepaintManager.java:64)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1720)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is the block of code that reports the error.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    paintFont(g);


    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
}

private void paintFont(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    for(int i = 0; i < fontArray.size(); i++){
        Image img = fontArray.get(i).getImage();
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < fontArray.get(i).getPaintLetters().size(); i2++){
            int x = fontArray.get(i).getPaintLetters().get(i2)[0]*Animator.pixMulti;
            int y = fontArray.get(i).getPaintLetters().get(i2)[1]*Animator.pixMulti;
            int xPaint = fontArray.get(i).getLetWpaint();
            int yPaint = fontArray.get(i).getLetHpaint();
            int imgX = fontArray.get(i).getPaintLetters().get(i2)[2];
            int imgY = fontArray.get(i).getPaintLetters().get(i2)[3];
            int imgXW = fontArray.get(i).getLetW();
            int imgYH = fontArray.get(i).getLetH();
            g2d.drawImage(img,x,y,x+xPaint,y+yPaint,imgX,imgY,imgX+imgXW,imgY+imgYH,this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the section of code getPaintLetters returns. paintLetters is what is returned.

```
ArrayList<int[]> paintLetters = new ArrayList<int[]>();

private void setArray(){
paintLetters.clear();

Point point;
int fontX = x, fontY = y;
int currentChar = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++){
    while(currentChar < strArray.get(i).length()){
        int lets[] = new int[4];
        point = setLet(strArray.get(i).charAt(currentChar));
        lets[0] = fontX;
        lets[1] = fontY;
        lets[2] = point.x;
        lets[3] = point.y;
        paintLetters.add(lets);
        fontX += 7;
        currentChar++;
    }
    currentChar = 0;
    fontX = x;
    fontY += 8;
}
strArray.clear();
}

public ArrayList<int[]> getPaintLetters() {
        return paintLetters;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your `getPaintLetters()` method.. when you do `.get(i2)` on this, at that instance the UI might not have been painted fully.. or a thread is in the process of painting letters when it tries to get `i2`

Comment: I recommend update that part of code in post

Comment: I added more of the code. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with threading. You are using Swing, and probably some UI element is drawn before the `paintLetters` variable is initialized. Where do you call 'your block'?

Comment: That block is being called by paintComponent. I added more to the code in the questing so it's more obvious how the code is called. I think you're right about the threading. This program does create a thread to run in but it's a single thread.

Comment: I think I may have found the cause of this. I had a bunch of static fields that I think were put into another thread. Making the arrays vulnerable. Dumb programming decision. I'll keep an eye out, the problem was rare so it might take a while to confirm. If I feel this solved the problem I'll post an answer.